# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: in Django 3.0

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have updated my project from Django 1.8 to Django 3.0

Here when i am trying display items using autocomplete i am getting this error

Here is my views.py

```
def autocomplete_items(request, flag=None):

    client = request.user.client
    q = request.GET.get('term')
    category = request.GET.get('category', '')
    job_items = JobItems.objects.filter(client_id=client)
    if category:
        job_items = job_items.filter(category_id=category)
    
    if flag:
        job_items = job_items.filter(stock='Variety Master')
    else:
        if client.horticulture:
            job_items = job_items.exclude(stock='Variety Master')

    products = job_items.filter(Q(item_name__icontains=q)|Q(soil_type__icontains=q)|Q(height__icontains=q)|Q(pot_size__icontains=q)|Q(form__contains=q)|Q(unit_price__contains=q)|Q(supplier_one__supplier_name__icontains=q)|Q(part_number__icontains=q)|Q(batch_number__icontains=q),is_deleted=False, is_one_of_item=False)

    res = []
    for c in products:
        
        #make dict with the metadatas that jquery-ui.autocomple needs (the documentation is your friend)
       
        dict = {'id':c.id, 'label':c.__str__()+ ' ('+ str(c.part_number)+')' if c.part_number else c.__str__() , 'label2':c.__str__()+ ' ('+ str(c.batch_number)+')' if c.part_number else c.__str__(), 'value':c.__str__(), 'partnumber': c.part_number}
        res.append(dict)
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(res[:15]))
```

Here is my models.py

```
class JobItems(models.Model):
     description = models.TextField(blank=True)
     item_name = models.CharField(max_length=512)
     part_number = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Stock number')
     batch_number = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
     client = models.ForeignKey("core.Client", related_name="job_items",on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text="Deleted tasks will not display in the UI.")
     is_checked = models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text="Save item into item details")
     created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
     modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
     quantity = models.DecimalField(
                max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0.00,
                verbose_name='Quantity In Stock')
     unit_price = models.DecimalField(null=True, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0.00, verbose_name='Retail price')
     
     def __str__(self):
        return self.item_name
     class Meta:
        ordering = ("quantity", )
```

here is my error traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/harika/lightdegree/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/harika/lightdegree/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/harika/lightdegree/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/harika/krishna test/dev-1.8/mcam/server/mcam/crm/views.py", line 19565, in autocomplete_items
    for c in products:
  File "/home/harika/lightdegree/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 276, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/harika/lightdegree/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1261, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/home/harika/lightdegree/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 57, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/home/harika/lightdegree/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1170, in execute_sql
    return list(result)
  File "/home/harika/lightdegree/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1569, in cursor_iter
    for rows in iter((lambda: cursor.fetchmany(itersize)), sentinel):
  File "/home/harika/lightdegree/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1569, in <lambda>
    for rows in iter((lambda: cursor.fetchmany(itersize)), sentinel):
  File "/home/harika/lightdegree/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 97, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 64, in convert_date
    return datetime.date(*map(int, val.split(b"-")))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'20 07:01:33.203614'
```

Here i couldn't understand why this error is occurring when trying to display autocomplete items

Comment: `val` appears to be `20 07:01:33.203614` which isn't an `int`. You probably need to ensure your input is a unix timestamp, or use a different method to convert a date string to date object.

Comment: Here i couldnt understand from where i am getting val  as i m not using date fields(i.e created_at ,modified_at)